# SOAP security, headers and Handlers In JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soaphandler

I am dabbling with SOAP web services in JAVA with JWS.

I want to implement custom headers that are constant for all webmethods provided so it would be inefficient to have the same parameter as an argument for all webmethods offered and declaring them as headers with the web param annotation.

My trouble is i can implement a protocol handler to ensure that all my custom header parameters are present and throw an fault in the event they are not however this is a restful approach as these parameters will not be defined in the WSDL created which to me would mean I am not strictly following the concept behind soap and the WSDL (that being it is the contract of communication between to applications.) This [example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxws-header-part-2-server) describes something similar but

"Parse undeclared custom headerLet's consider We need to read WSS UserToken non published in our WSDL :"

I need all the information required to be described in the WSDL both header and Body sections. All resources and questions on the matter are similar they just implement the handler but they are not described in the WSDL.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can say in your Web service interface that all methods throws CustomException. In generated WSDL they will present as fault in operation, then user or service will be in aware that SOAP call may throw an exception. You actual implementation of service will not throw those exceptions, but handler will do.